fills on zeros in KDB
Suppose i have
a: 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0
and I would like to forward fill the zeros to get
filled: 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
I tried using amend at @[]
a: @[a;where a=0;0N]; 
fills a

but i get the error:
'type
  [0]  a: @[a;where a=0;0N]

I've also tried replacing 0N with null and :: in the amend at statement but none of these approaches work. What do I do?

The issue is that you need to amend a as follows:
a:@[a;where a=0;:;0N]

Then you can get your expected output with:
0^fills a


Thanks @Thomas Smyth. Can you explain why the third argument : is required?

The 3 argument form is @[list;indices;function] and is trying to apply a function which is 0N in your case. The 4 argument form is @[list;indices;function;args] which is using the function : to amend those specific indices.

Although you wouldn't do it in this example, in general you can also try to create your own custom functions in these situations. For example a custom fills would look like:
/built-in fills is
q)fills
^\

/aka
q){x^y}\

/but a custom version based on filling zeros would be
q){$[y;y;x]}\[0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0]
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

If next item (y) is non-zero return y, otherwise return the previous item (x).
Of course, the custom versions will be slower than the optimised built-in versions!

Beautiful. This is my favourite

Agreed - this is elegant

If a is large and speed is important you may want to consider either this expression:
0^fills ?[a=0;0N;a]

or your original idea:
0^fills @[a;where a=0;:;0N]

Both are considerably faster than Terry's custom version of fill as he mentioned in his answer.

It's probably just pure coincidence, but with the example you provided and expected output maxs works as well
q)a: 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0
q)a
0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0
q)maxs a
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
q)


Your hunch is correct: only if the non-zeros form a monotonically increasing sequence. E.g., a: 0 3 1 0; maxs a would give 0 3 3 3.

Regarding speed, how @terrylynch 's solution is slower? Am I missing something?
q)\t:10000000 {$[y;x;y]}\[a]
10383
q)\t:10000000 0^fills @[a;where a=0;:;0N]
19465


"if a is large" is the key. What did you use for your a variable? The original list? In Terry's solution he is doing a conditional $ as well as a scan (iteration) over the whole list. While Igor's solution uses amend in place.
